# Swift: Aligning elements for multiple devices

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have a UIImage on a ViewController and under that I have a button (see crude example).

[image]

I can get the image and the button to center horizontally across devices but I cant get them to be centered.

Is it possible somewhere to use **%** as parameter so that the image will always be 25% from the top and the button will be also 10% from the image?

I am having real trouble getting simple elements to align up on all the different simulators.

If someone could also show me how to align the button up to the left of the image too that would be awesome :)

Comment: Yes, you can use an aspect ratio constraint.

Answer (score 0):

To set you image at 25% from the top, center it vertically in container (ctrl + drag from image to container) and then in Attributes Inspector, change the Multiplier value to 0.5 (this field is what controls the % you are looking for). 0.5 because image is already centered -> in 0.5 (0.5 x 0.5 = 0.25)

After that, select the button and set its top to your image´s bottom and set the multiplier value to 0.9.

To link the button to the left of the image you need to equal their Leading value.